# Updating a value on click once when multiple element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wMUTg/56/ that I'm trying to update a value by one when a button is clicked, only once. Similar to the 'like' functionality on facebook. I've got that working, however if I have multiple elements that are similar only one is updating. I know I have to use the $this functionality but I'm struggling to find where to put it. Also, does anyone know if this can be achieved without an input field? Ideally I'd like it to be in a span tag but I needed the input to get the value first.

```
$(".red #update").one("click", function() {
   var val;
   val = $('#counter').val();
   val++;
   $('#counter').prop('value',val );
});
```

Comment: Having more than one element with the same ID is invalid HTML. You should fix that - use a class instead.

Comment: here is a quick solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/5qnmwx94/

Comment: @CertainPerformance, is right. You should use class instead of same multiple IDs in one DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CertainPerformance, is right. You should use class instead of same multiple IDs in one DOM.

However here is your solution:

Used `$(this).prev('#counter')` as selector to refer relevant element.

```
$(".red #update").one("click", function() {
   var val;
   val = $(this).prev('#counter').val();
   val++;
   $(this).prev('#counter').prop('value',val );
});
```

Comment: Your welcome @FrazerFindlater, I am happy to help. Please accept my answer.

Comment: Will do, just have to wait 5mins first before I can.